# How to get both the current working directory and the current process in the status line for tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux, gnu-screen, productivity

I would like to have two status lines with the first status line showing which directory the window is in and the second one showing which process is running in the window. Is this possible? I use bash but I am open to switching to another shell if it is easier to make this configuration.

If this is not possible with tmux or very hard to configure, is there any other tool I can use which can provide me this info? (Basically I want multiple tabs/windows open in terminal, with the dir and process info.)

Answer (score 0):

A really good question.  I can get it to "work", but not well enough to be "usable", IMHO.  I agree that it would be a nice format, if it worked well enough.  I'll provide the info that I found here, in hopes that maybe you (or someone else who comes along) can fill in the rest of the puzzle.

Starting with tmux 2.9 in 2019, it's easy to add a second status line with `setw -g status 2`.  The format for the first line would be (a very *basic* version):

```
setw -g status-format[0] '#{W:#{pane_current_path} }' # or ...
setw -g status-format[0] '#{W:#(pwd) }'
```

The second line would be:

```
setw -g status-format[1] '#{W:#{pane_current_command} }' # or possibly
setw -g status-format[1] '#{W:#W } # if there's no other function changing the window title'
```

The problem is that these don't get aligned to each other, at all, and I haven't yet found a way to do so via tmux configuration directives.  There may be a way to at least pad/force both the top and bottom results to a certain width to create alignment that way, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Note also that, by default, tmux only updates every 15 seconds.  You can update this interval using something like `setw -g status-interval 1`.

Also note that any of the commands can be used interactively in the shell just by preprending the `tmux`  command.

Comment: Thanks for info, will try to get it work when I have some free time. The hardest part imo is getting them to align.